# Extracting output from `zlogit$sim()` (Zelig)

Tags: r, r-zelig

I'm still trying to get used to the totally new syntax the developers of `Zelig` are working towards (in Zelig5, instructions for installing the current development version [here](https://github.com/IQSS/Zelig)). Feels very Pythonic, except, not...

Anyway, I just want to store the results of a `sim` exercise, but can only figure out how to print the results to the console.

Let's use the example cited [in the documentation](http://docs.zeligproject.org/en/latest/zelig-tobit.html) (well, sort of--updated to reflect the Zelig5 syntax seen, e.g., [here](http://docs.zeligproject.org/en/latest/zelig-ls.html)):

```
set.seed(1234)
library(Zelig) #Zelig_5.0-5
ztob<-ztobit$new() 
ztob$zelig(durable~age+quant,data=tobin)
ztob$setx(ztob)
ztob$sim()
summary(ztob)

 sim x :
 -----
ev
      mean        sd      50%      2.5%    97.5%
1 1.534273 0.6350075 1.451001 0.5103966 3.042459
pv
         mean       sd      50% 2.5%    97.5%
[1,] 3.002031 4.027547 1.310886    0 13.19713
```

I don't really know what `pv` means (not really documented), but I'm pretty sure the expected value I want is 1.53 (under `ev`,`mean`).

Can anyone figure out how to extract that value? I can't find anything like `summary.Zelig` or `summary.zelig`; I've tried:

- `summary(ztob)$ev` / `ztob$ev`
- `print(summary(ztob))`
- `summary(ztob)[1]` / `summary(ztob)[[1]]`

Anything?

Comment: [here](http://docs.zeligproject.org/en/latest/installation_quickstart.html) are instructions for the development version and [here](https://github.com/IQSS/Zelig) is their github

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In cases like this, `str` is your friend.

You can get all the values:

```
x<-unlist(ztob[["sim.out"]][["x"]][["ev"]])
```

And the mean:

```
mean(x)
```

Comment: how did you use `str`, exactly?

Comment: calling it on each object - `str(ztob)` gives us the structure of ztob, and then you can go down levels once you find what you think is going to have your data - `str(ztob[["sim.out"]])` etc etc.

Comment: I was trying `ztob$` and looking at the autocompletes suggested by Rstudio--is this basically the same thing? sorry not at computer now...

Comment: str gives you the type of data each one is, and a few representatives, it's a much more detailed way of doing it.